# How can I limit how much a program can utilise my GPU?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, gpu

I'm currently running a program called `BOINC` [(BOINC website)](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/)

It is able to use my `GTX 1080` ti, however, it never seems to want to abide by its own settings on my system and so it hogs my GPU while I'm using my PC and it makes KDE feel slow.

Is there a way for me to get `Linux` to force the program to not take all the resources from my `GPU`?

I don't want to limit the GPU utilization for all programs and effectively handicap my system for no reason, just for that one so other programs can still use it. If that's not possible, what could I do to help mitigate the issue?

Perhaps I can change the GPU scheduler (if that's even possible)? I'm using the proprietary drivers btw. I'm perfectly fine with compiling and configuring the kernel if required.
(I asked this question yesterday at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444567/how-can-i-limit-how-much-a-program-can-utilise-my-gpu but nobody answered, so now i'm trying here)

Also, the main part of the program seems to be it's daemon, so if i can limit that it will likely work.